# react-select update value when mutating api data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select, react-query

i have a react-select component in which i am filing options from api data, whenever i am editing name of a person from api, the names in the options change but the name on the value remains same.

i want to change the value of select after i change the name of a person.

--here i am updating the name of a person using react-query

```
  const deliveryPersonUpdate = (values) => {
    const id = deliveryBoy && deliveryBoy.id;
    const params = { deliveryBoyId: id, ...values };
    updateDeliveryPerson.mutate(params, {
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        toggle();
        setDeliveryBoy(data?.delivery_boy);
        queryClient.invalidateQueries([GET_DELIVERY_BOY_LIST.name]);
        toast.success("Category Updated");
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        showErrorMessages({ error });
      },
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    deliveryPersonUpdate(values);
  };
```

--select component

```
<Select
 onChange={(obj) => handleChange(obj)}
                paintBg
                noOptionsMessage={noOptionsMessage}
                name="deliveryBoySelect"
                className={cx(styles.addDeliveryBoySelect)}
                defaultValue={
                  !isEmpty(data?.delivery_boys) && {
                    label: data?.delivery_boys?.[0].name,
                    value: data?.delivery_boys?.[0].id,
                  }
                }
                options={data?.delivery_boys.map((d) => ({
                  label: d.name,
                  value: d.id,
                }))}
                isSearchable
              />
```

--handle change for select

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const deliveryBoyData = data.delivery_boys.find(
      (obj) => obj.id === e.value
    );
    setDeliveryBoy(deliveryBoyData);
  };
```

--here, after changing name of person, options are updating right away but the value is not updating
[image]

Comment: did not understand your question properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you are using `defaultValue` for the select, which means the select is *uncontrolled*. Any time the `defaultValue` is changed, the select doesn't react to this change because it's not supposed to, it's just the default value.

You have two options:

1. make the select *controlled* (by using state)
2. make the select *keyed* (by re-mounting it when default value changes)

**As for controlled select**

You would have to replace `defaultValue` by `value` but also attach an `onChange` handler that changes the state. You kind of already have the `onChange` as it updates the state in RQ, but since you are using `defaultValue`, it doesn't propagate back. However, if you just used `value` I think there would be blinking because RQ is async by nature, so the user could see a frame where the value is still out of sync. So in order to fully do this, you would have to introduce a sync state as well.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value)
const onChange = (e) => {
  setValue(e.target.value)
  props.onChange(e.target.value)
}
useEffect(() => {
  setValue(props.value)
}, [props.value])

<select value={value} onChange={onChange} />
```

What this does it that it keep a local state using `setState`, handles update from props using `useEffect` and uses `value` instead of `defaultValue` thanks to that. You could also lift the state up if necessary.

**As for keyed component**

In case the previous solution is not ergonomic or not good for any reason and the component is small-ish, you can also decide that instead of keeping the local state, you will just unmount the component and mount a fresh instance. What the result is, is that when the value changes, it mounts a new component so it can use `defaultValue` again. You keep the select unchanged except for adding a `key` prop.

```
<select key={props.value} defaultValue={props.value} onChange={onChange}>
```

Having the key the same as the value means that they will be in sync. When the local value changes, it doesn't blink, because we do not set `value`, the DOM updates on it's own and when the `props.value` finally changes is async manner by RQ, it create the component anew, making it with the current `defaultValue`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Saved me a lot of time and headache.
This should be in the docs.